# Length of a cord pulled by moving block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, geometry

> The figure below shows a cord attached to a cart that can slide along a frictionless horizontal rail aligned along an x axis. The left end of the cord is pulled over a pulley, of negligible mass and friction and at cord height $h= 1.20$ m, so the cart slides from $x_1 = 3.00$ m to $x_2 = 1.00$ m. During the move, the tension in the cord is a constant 25.0 N. What is the change in the kinetic energy of the cart during the move?

This is the relevant figure:

[image: The relevant figure]

My approach was to describe the horizontal component of the force in terms of the continuously changing angle between the cord and the horizontal and then integrating it with respect to the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ - which gets me the correct solution.

However, I found a much simpler solution in the textbook: The work done is $W = Fd$, where $F$ is the tension in the cord and $d$ is the length of the cord pulled as the cart slides from $x_1$ to $x_2$. From the figure, we have $$ d = \sqrt{x_1^2 + h^2} - \sqrt{x_2^2 + h^2}$$
which yields $\Delta K = Fd = 41.7$ J.

So my question is: How can I get to the value of $d$ like that? From my own approach, the integral essentially contains that as well, but how do I get that geometrically, and does that then apply to every comparable situation or is there something special that makes this possible in this case?

Comment: I am not sure the simple Fd approach works here. Yes that gives the total work done. But that work is goes to overcoming friction and increasing kinetic energy. Friction depends on the normal component of force. That changes as the angle of the cord changes. So it sounds like you have to do an integral after all.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is more related to our constraint than to geometry.

If you notice carefully, the difference in the length of the string to the right of the pully is the length of the rope that moved to the other side of the pully. (As dictated by our constraint)

Consider the point on the end of the rope. The external force exerts a force F (the net force is 0) on it and it moves a distance d (which is the difference in the length of the rope on the RHS).

In the left side, the force makes an angle $0$ rad with the length of the rope, hence effectively , $W=Fd$

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here. The OP has stated that $d$ is the length of the cord pulled as the cart slides from its initial to its final position.

Comment: @PM2Ring, SORRY!!! Mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting this right you 're asking how to compute how much cord has been pulled. Imagine cord length at position $x_1$ as $l_1$ and at $x_2$ as $l_2$. Then the cord length, the height $h$ and $x_1$ or $x_2$ form an orthogonal triangle so the cord length in each position can be found from Pythagorean Theorem. Finally pulled cord lenght is $d=l_1-l_2$ with $l_1, l_2$ given by:$$l_1=\sqrt{h^2+x_1^2}$$$$l_2=\sqrt{h^2+x_2^2}$$ 
[image]